# Google Directions API Result is different from Google Maps result

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, directions

I am developing an app that displays the Distance & path between 2 distances. In this case I have used following addresses:

**Source:** Major Bhola Ram Enclave

**Destination:** Ring Road Mall, Sector 3, Rohini, New Delhi, Delhi

When I use Directions API then I get following result, see image below:
[image]

But, when I search these addresses in Google Maps then I get different Result.

[Click here to see Google Maps result](https://www.google.co.in/maps/dir/Ring+Road+Mall,+Outer+Ring+Road,+Sector+3,+Mangalam+Place,Rohini,+New+Delhi,+Delhi+110085/Major+Bhola+Ram+Enclave,+Pochanpur+Colony,+Dwarka,+New+Delhi,+Delhi+110075/@28.6294822,76.9989249,12z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x390d03e48c3afa29:0x7214e3803c41890d!2m2!1d77.1160218!2d28.6981159!1m5!1m1!1s0x390d1a56111bd22d:0x574e87f0efcc316f!2m2!1d77.0508597!2d28.5605831!3e0)
[image]
I searched a lot about this but I couldn't find any reason/solution for this.

Please guid me in right direction.
Thanks.

Comment: also the maps address is more relevant as it is showing the result within the same city : delhi whereas the directions API is showing result of some ram enclave in hyderabad which is like 1000 kms from the desination. You can see the screenshots above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are not addresses, they are places. If you want a similar result to Google Maps, you need to use the placeId or the coordinates returned for that place from the places service in the directions request.

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=Major%20Bhola%20Ram%20Enclave&addr2=Ring%20Road%20Mall,%20Sector%203,%20Rohini,%20New%20Delhi,%20Delhi&place=1&place=2

(uses the results from the place service)

[image]